# C# to VB.net error of is not defined

Tags: c#, json, vb.net

In C# its this:

```
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization

.....
[DataContract]
public class erUser : SerializedJson<erUser>
{
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public string UserID { get; set; }
```

Converting that to VB.net above gets me this:

```
<DataContract()> _
Public Class erUser
    Inherits SerializedJson(Of erUser)
    <DataMember(Name:="id")> _
```

Which gives me errors on the **DataContract()** and also **DataMember**.

The error is:

Type 'DataMember' is not defined.
Type 'DataContract' is not defined.

How can i fix this since im not an all-out C# programmer? :)

Comment: You need to import the namespace.

Comment: @webdad3 yeah doesnt make much sence.. i took it out :o)

Comment: @SLaks already have done that - still have the error.

Comment: Your c# code is suspect as there is no "Imports" directive in c#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both [`DataContractAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.aspx) and [`DataMemberAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.aspx) are found in `System.Runtime.Serialization`, as can be seen from the documentation links above.

So, import that namespace:

```
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization
```

Of course, you could omit that and use fully qualified names:

```
<System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract()> _
...
```

But that's not a whole lot of fun, so I do suggest that you import the namespace.

The other possible failure mode is that you have not added a reference to the assembly that implements these types. For both of these types that assembly is `System.Runtime.Serialization`.

---

As a general rule, when you encounter an error like this, you need to find the documentation of the name that cannot be resolved, and that documentation will tell you which namespace you need to import. For .net framework the information looks like this:

> ### Inheritance Hierarchy
>
> ```
> System.Object    
>   System.Attribute
>     System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute
> ```
>
> **Namespace**:  System.Runtime.Serialization
>   **Assembly**:  System.Runtime.Serialization (in System.Runtime.Serialization.dll)

The key information is here. As well as the namespace that you need to import, there is the assembly which implements the functionality. You must make sure that you reference any assemblies that you need to use.

Comment: I already had that in place: **Imports System.Runtime.Serialization** yet i still have the error?

Comment: So it's probably a missing reference. See the bottom of my answer.

Comment: It's quite odd because you get the exact same error message for both failure modes. Confused me for a minute.